# outofmemory exception for Large Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-camera, android-bitmap

I found a lot of documentation on how to load large Bitmaps and avoid outofmemory exception. but the problem is that I have to take the image from my MediaStore.Images.media so the classical 
`decodeFile(path,options)`  indicated in the google documentation does not work to me

As you can see below I decommented the line `// Bitmap photo= Mediastore.Images`, that is the one that triggers the out of memory. on the other side adding
the line `Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageToUri,options)` returns `null`, although the compiler can see both the path in `selectedImageToUri` (that indicates the content provider where the pics are) than the options value, that I set to 8, because I want to subscale all the images

My question is how can I insert in bm the bitmap that is referring to the image selected by the user in the gallery. in the line `BitMap photo` does not return null and work really well, but I decommented because after I change a couple of images gives me outofmemory exception.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (flagVariable) {

            if (selectedImageToUri != null) {


                // BitMap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(selectedImageToUri));


                final BitmapFactory.Options options= new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize=8;


                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageToUri, options);

                pic = new BitmapDrawable(bm);


                getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(pic);


            } else {
                getDefaultImageBackground(inflater, container);

            }


            hiddenList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_as_list_layout_temp, container, false);

        } else {
            getDefaultImageBackground(inflater, container);
        }

        listView = (ListView) hiddenList.findViewById(R.id.list_hidden);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MediaStore.getBitmap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/provider/MediaStore.java#MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap%28android.content.ContentResolver%2Candroid.net.Uri%29) is just a simple convienence method, it looks like this:

```
public static final Bitmap getBitmap(ContentResolver cr, Uri url)
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(url);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can create your own method based on this that takes the `options` and calls a different overload on `BitmapFactory`:

```
public static final Bitmap getBitmap(ContentResolver cr,
                                     Uri url,
                                     BitmapFactory.Options options)
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(url);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Usage:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;

Bitmap bm = getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                      Uri.parse(selectedImageToUri),
                      options);
```

Comment: thank you Weston, for your editing and for your reply, so I give you a reputation point, but I accept as reply Attaulah, that was first and further offered me also a nice quick win adding large heap to the manifest that is also an interesting alternative( although of course not optimal)

Comment: That's up to you, but for the record my answer was first. The order of answers is not chronological.

Comment: I am sorry from the bottom of my heart I did not know Weston. It would be an utopia to exchange your kindness trying to find a post where you are asking for help, because my level of knowledge is definitely distant years light  compared to yours, I am even still not an android developer for a living. My most sincere compliments for the gold head of your avatar, is just amazing imo. Really hope in future to be valuable for you. Again sorry Weston

Comment: Don't be silly! It's really up to you which one you accept, don't apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time on this problem, but no one will give me exact answer and finally i solved it. First create method and provide Image URI as argument, and this will return bitmap basically here i calculated image size on bases of, we can manage memory as well as image and get exact image in bitmap form.

you can even display 5000×8000 and 12MiB picture without any error code is tested just copy paste in your class and enjoy.

**Use**

```
Bitmap mBitmap = getPhoto(MYIMAGEURI);
```

**Provide URI to method and get Bitmap**

```
Bitmap getPhoto(Uri selectedImage) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    Bitmap photoBitmap = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
    int imageWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
    int imageHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    float scale = 1.0f;

    if (imageWidth < imageHeight) {
        if (imageHeight > width * 1.0f) {
            scale = width * 1.0f / (imageHeight * 1.0f);
        }

    } else {
        if (imageWidth > width * 1.0f) {
            scale = width * 1.0f / (imageWidth * 1.0f);
        }

    }

    photoBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(this,
            selectedImage, (int) (imageWidth * scale),
            (int) (imageHeight * scale));
    return photoBitmap;
}
```

**Decode Bitmap Sample using image size**

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Context context,
            Uri uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode editBitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    InputStream inputs = null;
    try {
        inputs = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputs, null, options);
}
```

**Calculate  Sample Size**

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = Math.min(heightRatio, widthRatio);
        // inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio :
        // widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Or may be possible to solved using one line of code in **`manifiest.xml`**
is in application tag use this

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Don't forget to close those streams. See my answer.

Comment: please edit my answer put where streams close are required.

Comment: No, your answer has too many other problems, if I only edit that bit of it, I'd share guilt on the other issues, and I don't have time for complete rewrite.

Comment: I would chose the Weston reply. LargeHeap does not work at all when I use a Samsung S5. The internal content provider does not allow to retrieve the MediaStore Images for security reasons, so I had to save internally the Bitmap with FileOutputStream, and still it gives me a lot of problems because i hit the exception: canvas trying to use a recycled bitmap.The Weston reply allows me to  fast subsample my image, and taught me how to  overwrite a method, also was first in replying. So I apologize, I am  newbe in  SO.Hope is ok with you. Sorry

Comment: alternative method already given in my answer. when you are using options.inSampleSize = 8; small image is reduce to 8x and this method only better for large image if you want use small image then image quality become too low. check your method for small image it will show what is result of the image. now as you wish what method you are using. but when you want to use image quality, on base of your device my method excellent work for that.